# Adding user defined java code to library

Tags: java

I have created a class in java i want to reuse the code just like java.lang has build in function without my project opened all the time how to do that.How to add my class to java library.

Answer (score 3):

- Make a jar file of your project.
- Add the jar file to build path of the project in which you want to use your first class
- Import the class in new project.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood your question right. Compile your code into a jar file and add it to your system's LD_LIBRARY_PATH or your consumer project's build CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just simply using your class then you can just import it from the package.

If your class is in other package(folder) you can import it like this:

```
  import packageName.className;
```

If your class is in same package you don't have to import the class to use it.